# Node.JS - filter() only works when hard coding in a index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Attempting to filter and array to get back objects that do not match with the user's input. Removing a book.

user's input: 
`{
    title: 'WindFall',
    author: 'Jaime',
    body: 'another body of a body'
  }`

array the filter is looking through (came from JSON then parsed):

```
    [
  { title: 'title1', author: 'samson', body: 'this is the body' },
  {
    title: 'WindFall',
    author: 'Jaime',
    body: 'another body of a body'
  }
]
```

Codebase:

```
function removeItem(item) {
try {
    const arrOfBooks = fs.readFileSync("./appendJSON.json").toString();
    const arrOfBooksParse = JSON.parse(arrOfBooks);

    const newArr = arrOfBooksParse.filter(item => {
        return arrOfBooksParse[item].title !== item.title;
    });
    console.log(newArr);

} catch (error) {
    console.log("There is nothing to remove");
}
```

}

Since I know the 2nd object `===` the user input, hard coding,

```
return arrOfBooksParse[1].title !== item.title;
```

works but `return arrOfBooksParse[item].title !== item.title;` does not. Instead the `catch` in `try/catch` fires off.

Comment: because you use the same variable!!!! `item` in function  and `item` in filter and you try to use both in the filter.

Comment: `arrOfBooksParse[item].title` but `item` is an *object* - you use it as such immediately after `item.title`

Comment: By `arrOfBooksParse[item]`, you probably just mean `item`. And then you have the issue that epascarello mentioned. Also, don’t wrap it in a `try`, that’s going to hide a lot of useful errors.

Comment: Have you tried indexing properly `.....filter( (item, index) = { return arrOfBooksParse[index].title ....`?

Comment: While the error here seems clear (as pointed out by those above me), I'll just re-iterate this for future knowledge: If you're asking a question about code that is not working, and that code is throwing an error, it's very helpful to share it :)

Comment: your variable so confuse. I think you should change the function removeItem(removingItem) first. Then in filter change to removingItem.title === item.title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item it is object from array. its no index. and "item" overrides "item" from arguments

fixed code:

```js
function removeItem(item) {
    try {
        const arrOfBooks = fs.readFileSync("./appendJSON.json").toString();
        const arrOfBooksParse = JSON.parse(arrOfBooks);

        const newArr = arrOfBooksParse.filter((i) => i.title !== item.title);
        console.log(newArr);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("There is nothing to remove");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. After I posted the question I realized that the 2 item key words may be an issue but still didn't figure out how to fix it. Your solution summed it right up. Thank you @Dzmitry

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
const newArr = arrOfBooksParse.filter(book => {
    return book.title !== item.title;
});
```

You just need to name the book something different (in the filter) than the `item` passed in.

Answer (score 0):

`item` in the callback is the actual item. Not the index. Using the item to lookup in the array is causing you to fall into the catch.

Instead of looking up the value in the array, the `filter` method provides you with the element. What you need to do is just rename one of your parameters, and use the item passed to you by the `filter` callback.

that would look something like this:

```
function removeItem(item) {
try {
    const arrOfBooks = fs.readFileSync("./appendJSON.json").toString();
    const arrOfBooksParse = JSON.parse(arrOfBooks);

    const newArr = arrOfBooksParse.filter(currentItem => {
        return currentItem.title !== item.title;
    });
    console.log(newArr);

} catch (error) {
    console.log("There is nothing to remove");
}
```